# :checked hack not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an effect that allows the user to click on the item image, which will result in the image popping up in the middle of the page and increasing in size. For some reason it doesnt allow me click it.

Here is the full jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gr282dxp/

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 0 0 -200px;
}
```

Comment: What's the exact problem ?

Comment: Nothing is happening. I can't click the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong selector.  You should be using `input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .img-container img` for your selector.

See [Adjacent Sibling Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)
and [Descendant selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)

https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/bwqbv9mn/

Comment: I could've sworn I tried that :) But I did it again and it works now. Thank you very much!